# Create an appendix title frame with just a title in beamer class

Tags: beamer, appendix, section-titles, frame-title

I want a section frame for the appendix, but only with a centered title, my normal title page and the baseline of all other frames with author, title, date and slide number shall remain unaffected.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\title{My title}
\subtitle{My subtitle}
\author{My name}
\institute[] {
    My university \\
    My faculty \\
    My institute 
}
\date{31. August 2023}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\AtBeginSection[] {
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Inhalt}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Normal Slide}
Test
\end{frame}

\appendix
% Here should be the titlepage with just "Appenix" on the frame.

\begin{frame}{Appendix frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mimic the title frame like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usecolortheme{default}

% PACKAGES
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title{My title}
\subtitle{My subtitle}
\author{My name}
\institute[] {
    My university \\
    My faculty \\
    My institute 
}
\date{31. August 2023}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\AtBeginSection[] {
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Inhalt}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Normal Slide}
Test
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}
\centering
\usebeamerfont{title}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}
Appendix % or \appendixname for automatic adjustement to the language
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Appendix frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @sp8cky You're welcome!